# Cancel all tasks if application runs longer than x

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task, task-parallel-library

I want to stop all running tasks if the application exceeds a certain runtime.
tokenSource.cancel() is being set but the tasks are still running till they end normally.  guess this is due to starting a process which runs the batch within cmd / the executable file. Do I need to kill the process, can I accomplish it with tpl, or is a completely different route beneficial?
I read about thread.abort() but it seemed rather unpopular.

I am starting a background worker from my Main Window which executes ExecuteDefault.

```
Background worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.doWork += (o, ea) =>
{ ExecuteDefault(worker, tokenSource);};
```

Within execute Default I access the execute function from the OSObject. All neccassary tasks will be started within this function. Now I want to cancel all tasks if the application is running longer than 350000ms.

```
private void ExecuteDefault(Backgroundworker worker, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
... random stuff
OSObject.RunSystemCommands(outputPath, execPath, timeframe, tasks, worker, tokenSource);
... random stuff
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), 350000);
tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Within here I start different Processes. Either Batch execution like \C logicaldisk or exe files like handle.exe are being executed.

```
aublic static void RunSystemCommands(string outputPath, string execPath, int timeframe, List<Task> tasks, Backgroundowrker worker, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    foreach(Command activeCommand in Commands.SystemCommands)
    {
        string keyname = activeCommmand.Name;
        if (keyname == "foo")
        {
        Task newTask = Task.Factory.Startnew(() =>
           {
           Executes.ExecuteBatch(outputFile, activeCommand)
           }, tokenSource.Token);
         tasks.Add(newTask);
        }
        else if (keyname == "bar")
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is how batch commands are executed.

```
 public static void ExecuteBatch(string outputFile, Command command, bool parse = false)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("Executing Task: {0} | Name: {1} | Command: {2}", Task.CurrentId, command.Name, command.Execute);
        log.Info("Executing Task: " + command.Name);
        //create new process and write process start information
        Process p = new Process();

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = command.Execute;
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;

        string delimiter = new String('=', 80);
        string output = "";
        string errorOutput = "";

        log.DebugFormat("Task {0}: writing outputFile for {1}", Task.CurrentId, outputFile);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputFile, (command.Execute.Replace("/C ", "") + Environment.NewLine));
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(outputFile, delimiter + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);


        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            errorOutput = "###Erroroutput### "+ eventArgs.Data + Environment.NewLine;

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(outputFile, errorOutput);

        };

        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args==null || args.Data==null || args.Data == "")
                return;

            output =args.Data+Environment.NewLine;

            if (parse == true)
            {
                output = Parser.ParseOutput(command.Name, output);
            }

            try
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(outputFile, output);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                log.Debug("Could not write to file. " + e.Message);
            }

        };

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        p.WaitForExit(command.Timeout)

        log.DebugFormat("Task: {3} | Name: {4} | Start: {0}, End: {1}, Elapsed: {2}", p.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), (DateTime.Now.Subtract(p.StartTime)).TotalMilliseconds, Task.CurrentId, command.Name);
    }
```

Comment: What's in Executes.ExecuteBatch? It would need to check for CancellationToken like in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988458.aspx) example and send the [Process.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) at moment's notice.

Comment: Flagging a task that it should quit either by Kernel objects or cancellation tokens won't achieve anything unless the task plays nice and periodically checks the object or token

Comment: I added what is inside the ExecuteBatch function.